# Unable to setup VSCode Go Extension

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, gopls

I enabled the Go VS Code extension and I get errors that I have to install gopls and other tools, so when I try to install it, I keep getting an error, and I have no intellisense or any features in my editor.

I installed Go 1.22 on my M1 Max Macbook Pro, and then opened VSCode and installed the extension. I can see in the output that I am getting this error from all the packages trying to be installed:

`/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_arm64/link: running clang failed: exit status 1 ld: building for 'macOS', but linking in object file (/private/var/folders/mn/5_9dh0hx2956g5b4v210dnfm0000gn/T/go-link-357213408/go.o) built for 'iOS-simulator' clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`